# ProjectionTo return ArgumentException: Argument types do not match

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, automapper

I try to build, some small chat app, first of all, I tried to fetch the list of created chat rooms, but when I fetch data from DB and try to map this by the Queryable Extensions: IQueariable.ProjectionTo() I got the error with a custom field. I use PostgreSQL, Automapper, EF core.

If i first serialize this list, it's working, but it looks dirty to me: two operations instead one.
for example, this works fine:

```
var rooms = await _context.Set<Chat>()
                .ToListAsync()
                ;
return Mapper.Map<List<ChatDto>>(rooms);
```

by the way, if i ignore Name props in Automapper profile, its works too! Even derived collection!

on the other hand, i thought its problem in different types of fields (i rarely use postgre), but if i change mapping, like this:

```
CreateMap<Chat, ChatDto>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Id.ToString()));
```

i got the same error ArgumentException: Argument types do not match, but id map fine.

**its return exception:**

```
var test = _context.Set<Chat>()
                    .ProjectTo<ChatDto>()
                    .ToListAsync()
                ;
```

part of stacktrace:

```
System.ArgumentException: Argument types do not match
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Bind(MemberInfo member, Expression expression)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl.EnumerableExpressionBinder.BindEnumerableExpression(IConfigurationProvider configuration, PropertyMap propertyMap, ExpressionRequest request, ExpressionResolutionResult result, IDictionary`2 typePairCount, LetPropertyMaps letPropertyMaps) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\QueryableExtensions\Impl\EnumerableExpressionBinder.cs:line 37
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl.EnumerableExpressionBinder.Build(IConfigurationProvider configuration, PropertyMap propertyMap, TypeMap propertyTypeMap, ExpressionRequest request, ExpressionResolutionResult result, IDictionary`2 typePairCount, LetPropertyMaps letPropertyMaps) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\QueryableExtensions\Impl\EnumerableExpressionBinder.cs:line 16
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.ExpressionBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<CreateMemberBindings>g__CreateMemberBinding|0(PropertyMap propertyMap) in C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\QueryableExtensions\ExpressionBuilder.cs:line 290
```

ChatEntity:

```
public class Chat : HasId<Guid>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ChatMember> ChatMembers { get; } = new List<ChatMember>();
    }
```

Dto:

```
public class ChatDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ChatMemberDto[] ChatMembers { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping:

```
CreateMap<Chat, ChatDto>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Name));
```

I clearly indicated the mapping of this field, although this is not required, of course

I try to check the execution plan, like this:

```
var test = _context.Set<Chat>()
                .ProjectTo<ChatDto>()
                .Expression;
```

but still, the same result.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Thx, i forgot this, but still the same output

Comment: For clarity, what AutoMapper version are you using?

Comment: @IvanStoev i use AutoMapper 7.0.1 for some reason (UseValue & ResolveUsing) Yes, i can change UseValue on MapFrom, but because of some problem i can`t do it for resolveusing (yes, i check documentation)

Comment: Thank you, honestly its part of the big project with outer api, but I`ll try to create a new app if the error disappears then I`ll find the way how to upgrade automapper and remove ResolveUsing.  I often use ProjecTo and it seemed to me that the problem is not in the version of the mapper

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. Just tried with that exact AM version and can't reproduce, so you are right - the AM versions seems to be irrelevant. Definitely needs minimal repro.

Comment: Hmm... that's weird, thx for the tutorial, I`ll try to reproduce that, i create a new whole project and put in another repo, thank you again, i appreciate it

Comment: @IvanStoev please refresh link about minimal repro. It's weird but I create a new project and copy-paste only chat functional, and ProjTo work fine... Only one difference between - at work I use Ubuntu, at home - win10. I created repo on github, i ll try to reproduce new project at work`s machine. It`s really awkward...

Comment: @IvanStoev I need dig deep in, at work's machine working too. I suppose my problem is middleware or somewhere in the pipeline

Comment: @EduardM did you get a solution for your problem? Im running into the same issue.

Comment: @jannikb Hi, yes, i figure this out a few months ago, I will publish the answer, Thank you for reminding me, I am very ashamed that I have not done this until now, but I did not fully understand the nature of this, so I wanted to experiment with the code. 
My problem was in EnumerableExpressionBinder (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/QueryableExtensions/Impl/EnumerableExpressionBinder.cs)

Comment: @jannikb in this class, the string was accessed as an array, it happened because I had a common mapping, something like CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing, this was done because almost all the lines that came to me were with a lot of spaces, it was my error, instead, it should be creating value transformers (http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Value-transformers.html), I hope this is useful, at least a little.

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't know, AutoMapper automatically maps arguments that have the same name automatically.
What I suspect is happening here, is that ChatEntity.ChatMembers, an ICollection, is conflicting when mapping to a ChatMemberDto[] on Dto.ChatMembers.

Comment: Sorry, it`s not this case, I therefore explicitly specified mapping for this field, the problem is in the string field

Comment: Whatever it's doing it's pretty useless if it doesn't tell me which argument is not matching :-(

Comment: @Simon_Weaver did you find how to find the argument causing the issue? Having the same problem here. Just a message saying argument not matching with no details